# How to install yugabyte-2.0.6.0/2.0.8.0 on centos7?

Tags: yugabytedb

environment:
os: centos7.6
kernel: 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
gcc version 4.8.5
Python 2.7.5
ip:10.1.2.3
host name: srvr0
fqdn:srvr0.example.org

I am trying to install yugabyte, as follows:
a) downloaded `yugabyte-2.0.6.0-linux.tar.gz`
b) extracted to `/opt/yugabyte`
c) added loopback addresses `127.0.0.2/8, 127.0.0.3/8, 127.0.0.4/8, 127.0.0.5/8, 127.0.0.6/8, 127.0.0.7/8` to interface `lo`
d) opened ports `7000, 9000, 7100, 5433,  9042, 6379`
e) run `/opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-2.0.6.0/bin/post_install.sh`
f) run `/opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-2.0.6.0/bin/yb-ctl --data_dir "/opt/yugabyte/data" create`

but getting error:

```
INFO: Waiting for master and tserver processes to comeup.
INFO: Waiting for master leader election and tablet server registration.
INFO: PIDs found:{'tserver': [None], 'master': [None]}
ERROR: Atleast one master or tserver is down.
^^^Encontered Errors^^^
```

Update1:
the ports are free ie.not used up by any service and the log files are empty:

```
/opt/yugabyte/data/node-1/disk-1/tserver.err
/opt/yugabyte/data/node-1/disk-1/tserver.out
/opt/yugabyte/data/node-1/disk-1/master.err
/opt/yugabyte/data/node-1/disk-1/master.out
/tmp/tmp098oCG
```

and status logfiles are not created:

```
/opt/yugabyte/data/node-1/disk-1/tserver.INFO
/opt/yugabyte/data/node-1/disk-1/master.INFO
```

Update2:
both `ps -ef | grep {yb-master pid}` and `ps -ef | grep {tserver pid}` has error:

```
[1]+ Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Update3:
earlier versions work.

Update 4:

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# grep "invalid opcode" /var/log/messages
Nov 29 15:28:18 srvr0 kernel: traps: yb-tserver[12192] trap invalid opcode ip:7fa69e2f4b8a sp:7fff91e8dd00 error:0 in ld.so[7fa69e2ec000+1b000] 
Nov 29 15:28:18 srvr0 kernel: traps: yb-admin[12199] trap invalid opcode ip:7f2476ebbb8a sp:7fffeaa0cfb0 error:0 in ld.so[7f2476eb3000+1b000]

[root@srvr0 ~]# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 37
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       M 620  @ 2.67GHz
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               1199.000
CPU max MHz:           2667.0000
CPU min MHz:           1199.0000
BogoMIPS:              5320.11
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              4096K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida arat spec_ctrl intel_stibp flush_l1d

[root@srvr0 ~]# uname -a
Linux srvr0 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 8 23:39:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## Update5 for yugabyte-2.0.8.0 (as on 22-Dec-2019):

```
Dec 21 19:14:54 srvr0 kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (3197 > 3181), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 62000
Dec 21 19:14:54 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:14:54 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:14:54 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:14:54 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:03 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:03 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:03 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:03 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:03 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:07 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:07 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:07 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:07 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:10 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:13 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:13 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:16 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:16 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:19 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:19 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:47 srvr0 journal: unable to create file '/run/user/0/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
Dec 21 19:15:49 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:15:49 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:16:01 srvr0 kernel: brcmsmac bcma0:1: wl0: brcms_c_d11hdrs_mac80211:  txop exceeded phylen 153/256 dur 1730/1504
Dec 21 19:16:03 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:16:03 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:16:23 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:16:23 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:16:53 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:16:53 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:18:32 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:18:32 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:18:44 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:18:44 srvr0 journal: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simple)' failed
Dec 21 19:19:35 srvr0 python: detected unhandled Python exception in '/opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-2.0.8.0/bin/yb-ctl'
Dec 21 19:19:36 srvr0 abrt-server: Executable '/opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-2.0.8.0/bin/yb-ctl' doesn't belong to any package and ProcessUnpackaged is set to 'no'
Dec 21 19:19:36 srvr0 abrt-server: 'post-create' on '/var/spool/abrt/Python-2019-12-21-19:19:36-15790' exited with 1
Dec 21 19:19:36 srvr0 abrt-server: Deleting problem directory '/var/spool/abrt/Python-2019-12-21-19:19:36-15790'
Dec 21 19:20:02 srvr0 systemd: Started Session 8 of user root.
[root@srvr0 ~]#
```

Please help me in installing and configuring yugabyte properly.

Comment: When you are saying "earlier versions work." - what is the latest version you were able to run successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Update:

This issue was addressed by https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/3044. Some versions of YugabyteDB that were using newer linuxbrew 
packages were affected by this issue. The 2.0.8 version of YugabyteDB fixes this issue.

Old:

It is possible that something else is running on one of the ports.

Can you please look at logs in the /opt/yugabyte/data directory for clues.?

For yb-master, look for master.err/master.out/yb-master.INFO files.
Similar, for yb-tserver look for tserver.err/tserver.out/yb-tserver.INFO files.

For example, use this to find the location of the err file.
  `find . -name "master.err" -print`

Comment: Saw your updates, especially: << [1]+ Illegal instruction (core dumped) >>


What architecture is the server? Can you share details of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` please?

If you can locate the core file, we can also try attaching gdb to it to find the exact instruction it is complaining about.

Comment: not server but old model laptop. cpu model name: Intel(R) Corei7(TM) CPU M 620 Core @2.67GHz. output size is big. whether it is manageable or output is needed!

Comment: Can you try:

`grep "invalid opcode" /var/log/messages`

to see if the output is helpful in investigating this further?

Comment: Nov 29 15:28:18 srvr0 kernel: traps: yb-tserver[12192] trap invalid opcode ip:7fa69e2f4b8a sp:7fff91e8dd00 error:0 in ld.so[7fa69e2ec000+1b000]
Nov 29 15:28:18 srvr0 kernel: traps: yb-admin[12199] trap invalid opcode ip:7f2476ebbb8a sp:7fffeaa0cfb0 error:0 in ld.so[7f2476eb3000+1b000]

Comment: Thx for the info. One more question-- can you also share the output of `lscpu` command? (Trying to check if you are on a 32-bit/64-bit OS).

Comment: And `uname -a` output

Comment: yugabyte-2.0.8.0-linux.tar.gz is not also working.  Please help me!

Comment: Are you still getting the "invalid opcode" error in /var/log/messages?