# How to build and install yugabyte db version 2.0.6.0 from github source?

Tags: cmake, configure, yugabytedb

a) downloaded yugabyte-db.tar.gz from github
b) created directory /opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-2.0.6.0
c) extracted to /opt/yugabyte
d) made /opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-master as present working directory
e) run ./configure --prefix "/opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-2.0.6.0" && make && make install
but getting error: `bash:./configure: No such file or directory`
Update1:
**Using yb_build.sh:**
**Prerequisites for yb_build.sh:**
note: package ctest3 is not available.

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# rpm -qa | grep python
libsemanage-python-2.5-14.el7.x86_64
python-gobject-3.22.0-1.el7_4.1.x86_64
python2-ipalib-4.6.4-10.el7.centos.noarch
python-schedutils-0.4-6.el7.x86_64
plasma-scriptengine-python-4.11.19-12.el7.x86_64
python-msrestazure-0.4.16-3.el7.noarch
python2-rpm-macros-3-32.el7.noarch
python-docutils-0.11-0.3.20130715svn7687.el7.noarch
newt-python-0.52.15-4.el7.x86_64
python-setuptools-0.9.8-7.el7.noarch
libvirt-python-4.5.0-1.el7.x86_64
python-netaddr-0.7.5-9.el7.noarch
python-ethtool-0.8-7.el7.x86_64
gnome-python2-2.28.1-14.el7.x86_64
python-lxml-3.2.1-4.el7.x86_64
python-kitchen-1.1.1-5.el7.noarch
python2-blockdev-2.18-3.el7.x86_64
python-decorator-3.4.0-3.el7.noarch
python-ldap-2.4.15-2.el7.x86_64
python-idna-2.4-1.el7.noarch
python-urllib3-1.10.2-5.el7.noarch
python-meh-gui-0.25.2-1.el7.noarch
python-firewall-0.5.3-5.el7.noarch
python-deltarpm-3.6-3.el7.x86_64
python-kmod-0.9-4.el7.x86_64
python-setproctitle-1.1.6-5.el7.x86_64
python2-requests-oauthlib-0.8.0-5.el7.noarch
python3-3.6.8-10.el7.x86_64
python-pillow-2.0.0-19.gitd1c6db8.el7.x86_64
abrt-python-2.1.11-52.el7.centos.x86_64
python-sssdconfig-1.16.2-13.el7.noarch
python-urlgrabber-3.10-9.el7.noarch
dbus-python-1.1.1-9.el7.x86_64
python-brlapi-0.6.0-16.el7.x86_64
python-qrcode-core-5.0.1-1.el7.noarch
python-configshell-1.1.fb23-5.el7.noarch
python2-cryptography-1.7.2-2.el7.x86_64
python-rtslib-2.1.fb63-13.el7.noarch
python-custodia-0.3.1-4.el7.noarch
python-netifaces-0.10.4-3.el7.x86_64
python-pyblock-0.53-6.el7.x86_64
python2-pyatspi-2.26.0-3.el7.noarch
python2-pyasn1-0.1.9-7.el7.noarch
python-cffi-1.6.0-5.el7.x86_64
python-pwquality-1.2.3-5.el7.x86_64
python2-pip-8.1.2-10.el7.noarch
python-ipaddress-1.0.16-2.el7.noarch
python-kdcproxy-0.3.2-1.el7.noarch
python-javapackages-3.4.1-11.el7.noarch
python-slip-0.4.0-4.el7.noarch
python2-subprocess32-3.2.6-13.el7.x86_64
python-chardet-2.2.1-1.el7_1.noarch
python-suds-0.4.1-5.el7.noarch
python2-futures-3.1.1-5.el7.noarch
python-ntplib-0.3.2-1.el7.noarch
python-pyudev-0.15-9.el7.noarch
python2-oauthlib-2.0.1-8.el7.noarch
libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.6.2-4.el7.x86_64
python-adal-0.4.7-1.el7.noarch
cryptsetup-python-2.0.3-3.el7.x86_64
python-slip-dbus-0.4.0-4.el7.noarch
policycoreutils-python-2.5-29.el7.x86_64
libuser-python-0.60-9.el7.x86_64
python-srpm-macros-3-32.el7.noarch
python-s3transfer-0.1.13-1.el7.noarch
python-nss-0.16.0-3.el7.x86_64
python2-ipaserver-4.6.4-10.el7.centos.noarch
python2-pyasn1-modules-0.1.9-7.el7.noarch
python-sss-murmur-1.16.2-13.el7.x86_64
audit-libs-python-2.8.4-4.el7.x86_64
python-ipaddr-2.1.11-1.el7.noarch
openlmi-python-base-0.5.0-4.el7.noarch
python-msrest-0.4.18-1.el7.noarch
openlmi-python-providers-0.5.0-4.el7.noarch
speech-dispatcher-python-0.7.1-15.el7.x86_64
libselinux-python-2.5-14.1.el7.x86_64
liblouis-python-2.5.2-12.el7_4.noarch
lvm2-python-libs-2.02.180-8.el7.x86_64
python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch
python-libs-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64
python-gssapi-1.2.0-3.el7.x86_64
python-inotify-0.9.4-4.el7.noarch
python-IPy-0.75-6.el7.noarch
python-perf-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
python-configobj-4.7.2-7.el7.noarch
python-backports-1.0-8.el7.x86_64
python-coverage-3.6-0.5.b3.el7.x86_64
python-azure-sdk-2.0.0-3.el7.noarch
python-blivet-0.61.15.72-1.el7.noarch
python-gobject-base-3.22.0-1.el7_4.1.x86_64
python-libipa_hbac-1.16.2-13.el7.x86_64
python-yubico-1.2.3-1.el7.noarch
python-devel-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64
python-dns-1.12.0-4.20150617git465785f.el7.noarch
python-augeas-0.5.0-2.el7.noarch
rpm-python-4.11.3-35.el7.x86_64
python-linux-procfs-0.4.9-4.el7.noarch
python-jwt-1.5.3-1.el7.noarch
python3-pip-9.0.3-5.el7.noarch
python-enum34-1.0.4-1.el7.noarch
abrt-addon-python-2.1.11-52.el7.centos.x86_64
python-cups-1.9.63-6.el7.x86_64
systemd-python-219-62.el7.x86_64
langtable-python-0.0.31-3.el7.noarch
python-urwid-1.1.1-3.el7.x86_64
python-requests-2.6.0-1.el7_1.noarch
python-meh-0.25.2-1.el7.noarch
python-six-1.9.0-2.el7.noarch
libpeas-loader-python-1.22.0-1.el7.x86_64
openwsman-python-2.6.3-4.git4391e5c.el7.x86_64
python3-libs-3.6.8-10.el7.x86_64
python-smbc-1.0.13-8.el7.x86_64
libreport-python-2.1.11-42.el7.centos.x86_64
python-isodate-0.5.4-8.el7.noarch
python-backports-ssl_match_hostname-3.5.0.1-1.el7.noarch
python-iniparse-0.4-9.el7.noarch
gnome-python2-canvas-2.28.1-14.el7.x86_64
python-rpm-macros-3-32.el7.noarch
python-boto3-1.4.6-5.el7.noarch
python-dateutil-1.5-7.el7.noarch
python2-ipaclient-4.6.4-10.el7.centos.noarch
python-pycurl-7.19.0-19.el7.x86_64
python-clufter-0.77.1-1.el7.noarch
python-ply-3.4-11.el7.noarch
python-di-0.3-2.el7.noarch
python-jwcrypto-0.4.2-1.el7.noarch
libstoragemgmt-python-1.6.2-4.el7.noarch
libxml2-python-2.9.1-6.el7_2.3.x86_64
python-pycparser-2.14-1.el7.noarch
python-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64
[root@srvr0 ~]# rpm -qa | grep ruby
ruby-2.0.0.648-33.el7_4.x86_64
rubygem-io-console-0.4.2-33.el7_4.x86_64
rubygem-psych-2.0.0-33.el7_4.x86_64
ruby-libs-2.0.0.648-33.el7_4.x86_64
ruby-irb-2.0.0.648-33.el7_4.noarch
rubygem-rdoc-4.0.0-33.el7_4.noarch
rubygem-bigdecimal-1.2.0-33.el7_4.x86_64
rubygems-2.0.14.1-33.el7_4.noarch
rubygem-abrt-0.3.0-1.el7.noarch
rubygem-json-1.7.7-33.el7_4.x86_64
[root@srvr0 ~]# rpm -qa | grep perl-Digest
perl-Digest-MD5-2.52-3.el7.x86_64
perl-Digest-SHA-5.85-4.el7.x86_64
perl-Digest-1.17-245.el7.noarch
perl-Digest-HMAC-1.03-5.el7.noarch
[root@srvr0 ~]# rpm -qa | grep epel-release
epel-release-7-11.noarch
[root@srvr0 ~]# rpm -qa | grep ccache
ccache-3.3.4-1.el7.x86_64
[root@srvr0 ~]# rpm -qa | grep git
libglvnd-glx-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
libglvnd-gles-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
lm_sensors-libs-3.4.0-6.20160601gitf9185e5.el7.x86_64
hypervvssd-0-0.34.20180415git.el7.x86_64
ipxe-roms-qemu-20170123-1.git4e85b27.el7_4.1.noarch
libwsman1-2.6.3-4.git4391e5c.el7.x86_64
python-pillow-2.0.0-19.gitd1c6db8.el7.x86_64
hypervfcopyd-0-0.34.20180415git.el7.x86_64
openwsman-client-2.6.3-4.git4391e5c.el7.x86_64
crontabs-1.11-6.20121102git.el7.noarch
squashfs-tools-4.3-0.21.gitaae0aff4.el7.x86_64
lldpad-1.0.1-3.git036e314.el7.x86_64
xdg-utils-1.1.0-0.17.20120809git.el7.noarch
LibRaw-0.14.8-5.el7.20120830git98d925.x86_64
libglvnd-egl-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
git-1.8.3.1-19.el7.x86_64
numad-0.5-18.20150602git.el7.x86_64
linux-firmware-20180911-69.git85c5d90.el7.noarch
python-dns-1.12.0-4.20150617git465785f.el7.noarch
taglib-1.8-7.20130218git.el7.x86_64
jboss-annotations-1.1-api-1.0.1-0.6.20120212git76e1a2.el7.noarch
lockdev-1.0.4-0.13.20111007git.el7.x86_64
polkit-kde-0.99.1-4.20130311git.el7.x86_64
libglvnd-1.0.1-0.8.git5baa1e5.el7.x86_64
net-tools-2.0-0.24.20131004git.el7.x86_64
hyperv-daemons-0-0.34.20180415git.el7.x86_64
openwsman-python-2.6.3-4.git4391e5c.el7.x86_64
hyperv-daemons-license-0-0.34.20180415git.el7.noarch
hypervkvpd-0-0.34.20180415git.el7.x86_64
[root@srvr0 ~]# rpm -qa | grep python2-pip
python2-pip-8.1.2-10.el7.noarch
[root@srvr0 ~]# rpm -qa | grep cmake
cmake3-data-3.14.6-2.el7.noarch
cmake3-3.14.6-2.el7.x86_64
[root@srvr0 ~]# rpm -qa | grep ctest
[root@srvr0 ~]#
```

**Installation log:**

```
    [root@srvr0 yugabyte-db]# /opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/yb_build.sh
...
    Verifying Linuxbrew archive checksum ...
    linuxbrew-20191015T202549.tar.gz: OK
    Installing Linuxbrew into /root/.linuxbrew-yb-build/linuxbrew-20191015T202549...
    fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
    Submodule 'submodules/yugabyte-bash-common' (https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-bash-common.git) registered for path 'submodules/yugabyte-bash-common'
    Submodule 'submodules/yugabyte-installation' (https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-installation.git) registered for path 'submodules/yugabyte-installation'
    [2019-11-30T20:49:36 common-build-env.sh:464 set_cmake_build_type_and_compiler_type] Setting build type to 'debug' by default
    [2019-11-30T20:49:36 yb_build.sh:983 main] YugaByte build is running on host 'srvr0'
    [2019-11-30T20:49:36 yb_build.sh:984 main] YB_COMPILER_TYPE=gcc
    Using third-party directory (YB_THIRDPARTY_DIR): /opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/thirdparty
    [2019-11-30T20:49:39 yb_build.sh:1210 main] Using make parallelism of 4 (YB_REMOTE_COMPILATION=0)
    [2019-11-30T20:49:39 yb_build.sh:353 run_cxx_build] Using cmake binary: /usr/local/bin/cmake
    [2019-11-30T20:49:39 yb_build.sh:354 run_cxx_build] Running cmake in /opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/build/debug-gcc-dynamic-ninja
    + export YB_REMOTE_COMPILATION=0
    + YB_REMOTE_COMPILATION=0
    + cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/build-support/compiler-wrappers/cc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/build-support/compiler-wrappers/c++ -G Ninja -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/root/.linuxbrew-yb-build/linuxbrew-20191015T202549/bin/ninja /opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-db
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:38 (project):
      Running

       '/root/.linuxbrew-yb-build/linuxbrew-20191015T202549/bin/ninja' '--version'

      failed with:

       Illegal instruction


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/build/debug-gcc-dynamic-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

    ==========================================================================================
    YUGABYTE BUILD SUMMARY
    ==========================================================================================
    Build type                       : debug
    C/C++ compiler                   : gcc
    Build directory                  : /opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/build/debug-gcc-dynamic-ninja
    Third-party dir                  : /opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/thirdparty
    Linuxbrew dir                    : /root/.linuxbrew-yb-build/linuxbrew-20191015T202549
    Exit code                        : 1
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**CMakeOutput.log:**

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# cat /opt/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/build/debug-gcc-dynamic-ninja/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log
The system is: Linux - 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 - x86_64
```

**Invalid OpCode:**

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# grep "invalid opcode" /var/log/messages
Nov 30 20:49:39 srvr0 kernel: traps: ninja[5039] trap invalid opcode ip:7f28d65eab8a sp:7ffe5291f890 error:0 in ld-2.23.so[7f28d65e2000+1b000]
```

Please guide me in compiling and installing yugabyte from source.

Comment: Looks like this is due to the fact that the ld.so version being used by yugabytedb contains instructions from AVX instruction set which seems to be not supported by Intel Core i7-620M.

Given the "invalid opcode" error you are running into here, it seems to be a duplicate of the issue you posted here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59080095/how-to-install-yugabyte-2-0-6-0-on-centos7

We'll keep you posted as soon as we have a resolution for this (i.e. support for processors without AVX). If you prefer, you can file this as a github issue against yugabyte-db.

Comment: Thx for reporting this. We are tracking this issue here: https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/3044.

A temporary patch to build YugabyteDB until then for processors without AVX support is here:

 https://gist.github.com/ttyusupov/1e8a234067a7669bda27e851d96aacd2

Comment: Whether does it requires AVX2?

Answer (score 0):

This issue (invalid opcode ip:7f28d65eab8a sp:7ffe5291f890 error:0 in ld-2.23.so) has been addressed by commit for https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/3044.

Some versions of YugabyteDB that were using newer linuxbrew packages were affected by this issue. The 2.0.8 version of YugabyteDB fixes this issue.